# Emulator and USB debugging issues in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I have recently updated my android studio from a very old version to the newest one. Now, when I cold boot an emulator I always the the following error: "The emulator process for AVD xxx was killed." I have tried reinstalling the SDK packages, freeing up space and a lot of other proposed solutions, nothing seems to work.

Furthermore, when I attempted USB debugging on my phone, it could not detect the ADB despite me clearly seeing it in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue after I forced stopped the emulator process from the task manager. In your case find out if the task manager is blocking the process. In my case I had to reset my Windows for this issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this link:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/95856597071/

Have you activated virtualization in the bios on your pc?